# full ng-table (sorting, search) not workink angular 10

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngtable, angular10

I'm trying to use [the full ng-table](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples), but it doesn't work with angular 10.

when I try to copy paste the code, an error appears here

```
@Directive({
 selector: 'th[mzSortable]',
 host: {
 '[class.asc]': 'direction === "asc"',
 '[class.desc]': 'direction === "desc"',
 '(click)': 'rotate()'
 }
})
```

the I tried to use this...

```
@Input() sortable: SortColumn = '';

@Input()
direction: SortDirection = '';

@Input()
@HostBinding('class.asc')
get ascClass (): any {
 return this.direction === 'asc';
}

@Input()
@HostBinding('class.desc')
get descClass (): any {
  return this.direction === 'desc';
}

@Output() sort = new EventEmitter<SortEvent>();

@HostListener('click')
rotate(): void {
  this.direction = rotate[this.direction];
  this.sort.emit({column: this.sortable, direction: this.direction});
}
```

now the table appear but I can't sort the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it, the problem was that I changed the Directive prefix.
replaced this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'th[mzSortable]',
} 
})
```

by this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'th[sortable]',
} 
})
```